# If sequence of functions coincide under composition then limits coincide under composition or not

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let X,Y be topological spaces and Z a metric space. Let $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of continuous functions from X to Z,$\{g_n\}$ is a sequence of continuous functions from X to Y and $\{h_n\}$ be sequence of continuous functions from Y to Z which converging to f,g and h respectively. Then if $f_n = g_n \circ h_n$ for all n then under what condition we can say $f = g \circ h$ ?

Comment: If $g_n$ and $h_n$ are functions from $X$ to $Y$ their composition may not be defined.

Comment: You should specify the domain and codomain of these functions (you never mentioned what $X$ and $Y$ have to do with any of these functions). Assuming these compositions make sense, it seems to me that what you want is local uniform convergence of the $g_n$.

Comment: With appropriate hypothesis on the domains and ranges a set of  sufficient condtioins is continuity of $g$ and uniform convergence of $g_n$ to $g$.

Comment: Which type of convergence do you consider? Pointwise, ... ?

Comment: yes, the convergence is pointwise.... If the convergence is uniform then it holds I think @ Paul Frost